# VPN connection over apache mod_proxy

Tags: vpn, connection, mod-proxy

We have several virtual machines which are connected in a private virtual network connection.
Internet access for these machines is provided via dedicated virtual machine which has apache proxy server on it (they all use this machine as proxy).
The problem now is that from several machines we need to connect to external VPN Server, but it seems that VPN connections don't work over apache proxy.

Any suggestions on how to enable VPN connection over apache proxy (or some other proxy)?
Some other solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache's mod_roxy is for proxying HTTP traffic, you're not going to get VPN traffic over it. If you need to set up a VPN to an external VPN server, you're going to have to setup a gateway to route the traffic out from the private network to the external world. It might be possible to get the box that's doing the proxying to also act as a gateway.